# first and multiple response request ajax so slowly in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am confused here, when I use modal click with jquery and get very slow ajax response when I make a request at first and two or more requests (Google Chrome), but when I try in another browser it is not slow response (Firefox).

In Google Chrome console :

```
------------------------------------
|   Name   |   Status   |   Time   |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   434 ms |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   145 ms |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   438 ms |
------------------------------------
```

In Firefox console :

```
------------------------------------
|   Name   |   Status   |   Time   |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   145 ms |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   153 ms |
------------------------------------
| getData  |    200     |   143 ms |
------------------------------------
```

Jquery code :

```
$("#myTable").on('click', '#myModal', function () {
      var myId = $(this).attr("my-attr");
      $.ajax({
          url: `my-url/my-controller/myId`,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
             myId: myId
          },
          success: function(success) {
             console.log(success);
          }
      });
});
```

For Backend I using laravel, and this is my controller :

```
public function getDataId($myId) {
    $ids = array_map('intval', \explode(",", $myId));

    $getDataQuery = MyModel::select('selecting all my data what I want use')
                    ->join('all my table join')
                    ->whereIn('my_id', $ids)
                    ->first();

    return response()->json([
        'getData' => $detailPayment
    ], 200);
}
```

Any problem with my code, which is making my responds so slowly? Thank You

Comment: try using fetch instead of jquery bloat - shouldn't make a difference, but who knows what jquery does "under the hood" - best to compare native fetch ... or even XHR

Comment: so I must try native fetch to look what is different? When it's nothing change, what should I do? But I still not understand yet why google chrome make a slow response compared with firefox

Comment: no, I didn't say you MUST ... I suggested it, taking jquery out of the equation (I once took jquery out of the equation in a website and got 10x speed improvement overall)